# Give keyboard shortcuts priorities to my keyboard layout over Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, keyboard-shortcuts, word-2010, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I want a trilingual English-French-German keyboard with the [Dvorak layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) on Windows 7. I made it myself with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator v. 1.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). For some letters I have to assign five variants (e, é, è, ê, ë plus the capital versions). Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator only allows Ctrl-[key] and Alt-Ctrl-[key] to make alternate characters (not Alt-[key], unfortunately). I had no choice but to use the Ctrl-[key] sequence to produce a lot of keys.

In almost every program (e.g. Firefox) the keyboard has priority over program-defined shortcuts, so that if Ctrl-u is a defined key on my keyboard, the Firefox shortcut with Ctrl-u is frozen. This is what I want in Microsoft Word 2010. But even if I delete the Word 2010 shortcuts in File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard Shortcuts Customize, Word still has control over the Ctrl-[key] sequence. That is, if I kill the Ctrl-f (find) shortcut in Word, and then press Ctrl-f, nothing will happen: find will not open and my Keyboard assigned Ctrl-f character is not printed.

How can I give priority to my custom-defined characters over Word's Ctrl shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably going to be using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) to do your layout mappings.  AHK basically monitors the keyboard buffer at the OS level, so it is able to intercept and correct keystrokes before the other programs can react to them.  I can confirm that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in AHK does overwrite the keyboard shortcuts in Word 2010.

Some sample AHK code:

```
^f::Send {U+00C6}   ;Ctrl+F sends Æ
!f::Send {U+00C7}   ;Alt+F sends Ç
!^f::Send {U+00E8}  ;Ctrl+Alt+F sends è
!^+f::Send {U+00C8} ;Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F sends È
```

<kbd>^</kbd> intercepts a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keystroke, <kbd>!</kbd> intercepts <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>+</kbd> intercepts <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and they can be combined.  The `{U+xxxx}` corresponds to the Unicode number for the given character.

Using this method allows you to keep your keyboard mapping in a simple txt file (easy to backup or transfer to another computer).  It also overrides shortcuts in all programs, so you won't have to re-adjust the shortcuts for each new program you use.